# Unable to add a facebook app that allows publishing from Wordpress

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create a facebook app that will allow me to publish from my Wordpress site. I have been through much of the facebook help docs (which are out of date making it somewhat more difficult) and a bunch of external how to's as well.

I have been inching my way towards completion but I am stuck and I am unsure where to turn.

I have created the app and linked it to my wordpress site. From the site users can like and share, I also have a number of the widgets (like the page, other recommendations) working.

I would now like to publish articles to my facebook page and this is where I am having trouble.

I have added the publish action, article object combination and I would like to submit it for approval but it is ineligible because:

> You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action at least once.

Seems simple enough. I followed the instructions under "Publish your first Open Graph action" on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/wordpress/open-graph-action/

When I submit I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3506) The action type news:Publish does not exist or is not approved, so app XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not one of those roles.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3506
  }
}
```

My account is the only account attached to the application and has administrator role. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my own question, I had not selected the correct Application at the top of the Graph API Explorer page. Changing that and generating a new access token got it working.